# Form of a monotonic decreasing function

Tags: real-analysis

If I have a function $y(x)$ which is non-negative and decreasing for $x<0$ and has a minimum at $x=0$, i.e.,
\begin{align}
y(x)& \geq 0 \quad \text{for} \quad x<0,
\\
y'(x)&<0 \quad \text{for} \quad x<0,
\\
y'(x) &= 0 \quad \text{for} \quad x=0,
\end{align}
can I conclude that $y(x) \in O(x^2)$? Or can I conclude even more precise form of the function?

Answer (score 2):

No, those first-order informations are not enough to conclude anything like that.

As a counterexample consider the function $y:\mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$ defined by
$$
y(x) = \lvert x \rvert^{3/2} 
$$
Then $y$ satisfies all of your conditions but is not in $O(x^2)$ as $x \to 0$.
If you're interested in the asymptotics for $x \to \infty$ then there's also multiple easy to find counterexamples.

Comment: No you can't have anymore information on $y(0)$ since you can just add non-negative constants to the example I gave.